# constructing xml within ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser

I am sending a request back to the server I am communicating with, the gist of this request will have a bunch of different parameters, like user ID, request number etc. 
One of the more important parts of the request is a segment of XML that im hoping to create based of a few user selections in my interface.

Then at the end i will wrap this all up and send it off to the server...

However at the moment I have no idea how to form an segment xml, I have been reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/ConstructingTrees.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002268-BCIEABEE) but im not sure how it relates to what I would like to do.

any help, example code, example tutorials or anything would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A plist is just xml [with a strict dtd](http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd); and you can use `NSPropertyListSerialization` to create one to send back to the server from an NSArray/NSDictionary, very easily.

Comment: cheers for putting the strict in my dtd dawg! lol, I'm going to look into these suggestions now.. :P cheers.